# How do I deliver a large amount of documentation in a portable format?

Tags: windows, documentation, full-text-search

I have a documentation set that I need to deliver to a variety of users. It is currently in HTML with a number of attachments with a total size of around 180MB. I have the following requirements:

1. It only needs to be viewable on windows.
2. The user must not need to install additional software prior to viewing the documentation over and above what is normally on the machine (MS Office, browser etc)
3. The entire set needs to be searchable (preferably including MS Office attachments)
4. (desirable) It needs to be distributable as a single file (.exe OK)
5. (desirable) It needs a compatible authoring tool

Any ideas on what would be a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One tool that we are considering to do this is [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/) which allows inline editing of the source and can be extended with plugins to look more like a traditional website and to provide better support for multi user editing.

Answer (score 1):

Way out of my area of expertise, and it may not work with the office files, but [Microsoft Compiled HTML Help](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help) looks promising.